# Logstash multiplying output when using pipeline to pipeline

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I'm trying to use Logstash to filter and send logs to Elastic and Slack.
If I test only slack config it works fine. Only 1 message for 1 error is sumited to Slack.
if I test only elasticsearch config it works fine. Only 1 message per error is submited to ES.

but when I try to use Pipeline to pipeline config (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/pipeline-to-pipeline.html) all messages get multiplied by manytimes. 1 error has more than 300 index values and 300 messages in Slack.

Config:
beats.conf

```
input { 
    beats { 
        port => 5044
    } 
}
    
output { 
    pipeline { 
        send_to => ["inputElastic","inputSlack"] 
    } 
}
```

slack config

```
input {
    pipeline {
        address => "inputSlack"
    }
}

filter {
    json {
        skip_on_invalid_json => true
        source => "message"
        target => "stdout"
    }

    if [stdout][log.level] != "ERROR" {
        drop { }
    }
} 

output {
    slack {
        url => "https://hooks.slack.com/services/******/*****"
        format => "%{[stdout][log.level]}: %{[stdout][error.message]}" 
    }
}
```

elastic config

```
input {
    pipeline {
        address => "inputElastic"
    }
}

filter {

    json {
        skip_on_invalid_json => true
        source => "message"
        target => "stdout"
    }
}

output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "elasticsearch:9200"
        user => "logstash_internal"
        password => "${LOGSTASH_INTERNAL_PASSWORD}"
        index => "index-%{+YYY.MM.dd}"
    }
}
```

config/pipelines.yml

```
- pipeline.id: input-beats
  config.string: |
    input { beats { port => 5044 } }
    output { pipeline { send_to => ["inputElastic", "inputSlack"] } }

- pipeline.id: input-elastic
  path.config: "pwa.config"
- pipeline.id: input-slack
  path.config: "pwa-slack.config"
```

I'm probably missing something, just can figure out what.

Tried all config individualy, works fine.
When try to run them together, fails with too many messages.

Idea is to have ERROR(s) submited directly to Slack (instant) and save all other details to Elastic to be able to check them any time (Kibana).

Comment: Just to add. I know I could use multriple outputs (for slack and es) but this is not a final idea what I need to do.
I realy need to figure out this "pipeline to pipeline" method.

Answer (score 0):

If you have [multiple pipelines](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/multiple-pipelines.html), you need to configure them in `pipelines.yml` otherwise all inputs get merged together, all filters get merged together and all outputs get merged together.

```
- pipeline.id: slack_pipeline
  path.config: "/etc/path/to/slack.config"
  pipeline.workers: 2
- pipeline.id: elastic_pipeline
  path.config: "/etc/path/to/elastic.config"
  pipeline.workers: 2
```

Comment: ```- pipeline.id: input-beats
  config.string: |
    input { beats { port => 5044 } }
    output { pipeline { send_to => ["input-elastic", "input-slack"] } }

- pipeline.id: input-elastic
  path.config: "pwa.config"
- pipeline.id: input-slack
  path.config: "pwa-slack.config"```
This is what I had in pipeline.yml

Comment: Can you update your question as it's more legible than in comments

Comment: Thanks, can you clarify what you mean by "fails with too many messages."? And can you also show the command you're using to run Logstash?